# Can't sell Steam Cards, Can Sell Booster Packs?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

What has changed with Steam Marketplace, and/or my account, that would prevent me from selling Steam Trading Cards (can convert to Gems)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's now impossible to sell on marketplace cards/emoticons/backgrounds from games, that were removed from store. Check if related game is still available in steam store.

[This post](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/card-trading-card-trades/discussions/1/133255957994868314/) contains *incomplete* list of such games.

However, you can still trade these items with other players, turn them into gems and craft badges from cards.

Comment: This appears to be it. Just checked, and the cards in my inventory do not have store pages.